# Translating error messages Material-ui

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui

I have a form using Material-ui TextField and I'm translating all my fields like this :

```
 <TextField autoFocus={true} name='formName'
                   placeholder={this.context.intl.formatMessage( translations.formNameInputPlaceholder )}
                   value={value || ''}
                   fullWidth={true}
                   errorText={ this.shouldShowError( fieldValidity ) ? <FormattedMessage { ...translations.notValid} /> : null }
                   onChange={ e => onChange( e.target.value ) }/>
```

however errorText is never translated and keeps using default locale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this problem was solved in react 15.2.1

https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/2494